# R plot_ly hoverinfo

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm using plot_ly in a shiny app. I've the following function

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y , key = df$id, type='scatter', mode="markers",
name = "Clusters", opacity = point.opacity, text = df$id, hoverinfo = "text")
```

If the length of *df$id* is not 0 then everything is fine. If the length is 0 because no data is available I get the following error: `Error in : Column 'hoverinfo' must be length 0, not 1`. If I omit hoverinfo, then everything is fine with the empty dataset.

How can I fix this? I tried to use ifelse but that doesn't work. My solution is to define a if statement and then call plot_ly with or without hoverinfo. Does anybody have an better idea?

Comment: Can you improve the data input instead? E.g. find all cases where `id` is of 0 length, and replace it with some default value `df$id[nchar(df$id) == 0 | is.na(df$id)] <- "missing"`

Comment: No, i filter the data frame before. After the filtering process, the dataframe is empty. So that the data frame has 0 rows in some cases.

Comment: In that case, I don't see what's wrong with having `if(nrow(df) > 0){ plot_ly(...)}else{NULL}`. There's no point running the `plo_ly` command if there is no data (I'm guessing) :)

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I just want an empty plot in this case because I have 4 plots next to each other.

Comment: Doesn't look like a plotly error. Plotting empty dataframe works fine with your code (v4.7.1)

Comment: No, but the problem is with hoverinfo, because if I use hoverinfo = "none" the same error appears

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/plotly/man/plotly_empty.html

Comment: Thanks Jonny Phelps